# How to print char array in C, like 'Arrays.ToString(array)' of Java?

Tags: c, arrays, char

I want to print char array in C like `Arrays.ToString(array);` of Java does. It prints what I want but puts some characters at the end. I guess it's because of the special character `\0`.

I declared a char array `char letters[] = {'g','y','u','c','n','e'};`

And tried to print: `printf("\n [%s]:", letters);`

The output is: `[gyucneÇ_=]`

Here is the Java code:

```
    char[] letters= {'g','y','u','c','n','e'};
    System.out.print( Arrays.toString(letters) );
```

The output is:

`[g, y, u, c, n, e]`

I wanted to have the output of Java code. I wonder if I want it to contain commas too, do I have to print the characters one by one or can I print it at once ?

And of course my priority is to remove the special character that is printed at the end of C code.

Comment: Why don't you declare the array as `char letters[] = "gyucne";`?

Comment: C strings are null-terminated, meaning that they contain a byte with value 0 to mark the end of the string data.  A `char` array that does not contain such a terminator is not a string, and attempting to use it as if it were produces undefined behavior.  The result you present demonstrates one of the innumerable possible manifestations of UB.

Comment: What is the difference ?

Comment: Difference between `char letters1[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};` and `char letters2[] = "abc";` is that letters1 has 3 elements and letters2 has 4 elements, the 4th element being `letters2[3] == '\0'`.

Comment: Don't change questions after they have been answered (rolled back)!! **And don't forget the `'\0'` string terminator.**

Comment: I tried to add a new question. It warned me like improve your other questions.

Comment: It is a new question, not an improvement of this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print each letter on its own. You do not have a string. You cannot call most functions from `<string.h>` or `printf()` or a bunch of others that expect a *string*.

```
char letters[] = {'g', 'y', 'u', 'c', 'n', 'e'}; // ATTENTION: letters is not a string!
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof letters; i++) {
    putchar(letters[i]);
}
putchar('\n'); // end with a newline
```

Comment: Kind of: it would print a byte with `0` value which might show up with some fancy character. With `char letters[] = "gyucne";` you have a proper string. It would be easier to print with `printf("%s\n", letters);`

Answer (score 0):

> I declared a char array:  `char letters[] = {'g','y','u','c','n','e'};`

But that is *not* a C string (since it is *not* <kbd>NUL</kbd> terminated ! ). You should have coded instead:

```
const char letters[] = {'g','y','u','c','n','e',(char)0};
```

(or use `'\0'` instead of `(char)0` ....) or better yet:

```
const char letters[] = "gyucne";
```

and both are *exactly* equivalent.

Then you can code something like `printf("letters are %s\n", letters);` since your `letters` are now a C string.

NB. Please read also http://utf8everywhere.org/ & [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) - both are practically very relevant for your case. See also at least some [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) site.